# Limiting number of AWS EC2 instances a user can create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

AWS IAM provides quite granular permissions in regards to the specific types of instances that can be launched by a specific user.

However, I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom policy that would enable me to set an upper limit on the number of EC2 instances that can be created by an individual user (not an account)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS doesn't store which user has launched which machine.

One bypass I recently did was to externalize the logic into a Rundeck job:
the job was calling a python script, in which I controlled the number of instances launched by the user before actually creating a machine or not. The username was taken from the Rundeck user running the script (rundeck was pluged on active directory) and stored in AWS through tags

hope this helps